# What is the best way to make a detail page from an object list?

Tags: reactjs

In my React project, I use `<Link/>` component to pass the store object when user clicks one from the store list. However, if I use this way, I can't access through the link, even though the user gets the url by clicking the link. As I work on `Search Engine Optimization (SEO)`, I need to allow users to access the store detail page by url.

**Component example**

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/${store.domainKey}`,
    state: { store: store }
  }}
>
  <img ...>
</Link>
```

I'm getting data through APIs. If so, what is the best way to make the link? Should I make a API with a parameter referencing a store for its detail page?

Comment: like this `/store/details`?

Comment: yes but the point is not how the url looks. The point is if I use Link component in the above way, people cannot access the detail page through url directly without using the link

Comment: user can enter into that link directly, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the Store from `<Link />` to the component, your components should be self-sufficient. Therefore when the user opens a route directly, let's say `/books`, your component will be responsible for:

1. Fetching the needed data from the API firstly and keep it in the Store.
2. After that, it will render all the Books.

I would suggest you to read about [Containers and Presentational components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

According to the above flow, the Container will be responsible for data fetching (step 1) and the Presentational component will be responsible for rendering the Books (step 2).

Comment: Thank you! So, based on that, I came up with the following. When I click the image of store, the clicking passes id number the store as props to `<StoreDetail />` or something like that. After that, `container.js` takes the id number prop and fetch API with it to get the store data. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you for the double check!